# Fix numbers count after point for decimal

Tags: c#, .net

How I can fix digits count after point for decimal type **WITHOUT ROUNDING** 
in C#.

For example:
decimal coords = 47.483749999999816; (part of geographic coordinates)

I need to stay only 6 digits after point: 47.483749

Comment: Why **without rounding**?

Comment: Do you need string representation of your decimal to have 6 digits?

Comment: If you just want to display the coords use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: Not sure if it is the best option but you could make a string, then cut off the digits and turn it back into a number. Sounds dirty. but to be honest i'm not sure if theres a better solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use

```
decimal truncated = Math.Truncate(coords * 1000000m) / 1000000m;
```

or maybe

```
decimal truncated = Math.Truncate(coords / 0.000001m) * 0.000001m;
```

Of these two, I have come to prefer the latter. The number `0.000001m` is represented internally as the mantissa `1` together with the scale `6`, so dividing and multiplying by it is effectively just a move of the decimal point by six places.

The method where you multiply by `0.000001m` in the end tends to give a result with exactly six digits after the decimal point, even with trailing zeroes if necessary. For example `coords = 1.23m` will lead to `truncated` being `1.230000m`.

As noted in the comments, the above techniques will both lead to an **`OverflowException`** if `coords` is too huge (more than one millionth of the `decimal.MaxValue`).

For completeness, here are a couple of other solutions:

```
decimal truncated = coords - coords % 0.000001m;
```

This seems to work fine. The number of trailing zeroes will not always be correct though, but I believe it gives the same result wrt. the `==` operator (or `decimal.Equals`).

Finally, you can use:

```
decimal truncated = Math.Round(coords - 0.0000005m, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

but that works only for non-negative `coords`.

If what you really need is a formatted `string`, call a `ToString` overload on `truncated`. But beware, as I indicated, of trailing zeroes. If you use `.ToString("F6")` there should always be exactly six decimals.

Of course you can also use string manipulation for the truncating. It would go something like:

```
string coordsString = coords.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int idxOfPoint = coordsString.IndexOf(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
if (idxOfPoint != -1 && coordsString.Length > 6 + 1 + idxOfPoint)
    coordsString = coordsString.Remove(6 + 1 + idxOfPoint);

// coordsString is now truncated correctly.
// If you need a decimal, use decimal.Parse(coordsString)
```

Comment: coords * 1000000m can overflow

Comment: +1. @DmitryDovgopoly, you are right for extreme values close to 10^23... from sample it looks like values are realively small - so likley to be fine.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Upon a little consideration, I prefer the second option that I added. It feels better to do the multiplication last, and `0.000001m` will be represented as a `1` mantissa with a scale of `6`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Very tricky, and not suggested, but I don't really know what solution are you looking for (since you're avoiding `rounding`):

```
double k = 47.483749999999816;
k = double.Parse(Regex.Replace(k.ToString(), @"(\d+\.\d{6})(.\d+)", x => x.Groups[1].Value));
Console.WriteLine(k);
```

that prints

```
47.483749
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   decimal.Round( 47.483749999999816, 6)
```

Comment: The questioner asks solution WITHOUT ROUNDING